# How to turn on AMD Turbo Core for AMD A6 6310 on Linux?

Tags: ati, cpu, turbo-boost

I use Lubuntu 15.04
I've noticed that my processor (AMD A6 6310) works at 1800 MHz frequency and not more, while AMD promised 2,4 GHz with Turbo Core option.

How to enable Turbo Core option?

```
$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
driver: acpi-cpufreq
CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
maximum transition latency: 4.0 us.
hardware limits: 1000 MHz - 1.80 GHz
available frequency steps: 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz
available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
current policy: frequency should be within 1000 MHz and 1.80 GHz.
              The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
current CPU frequency is 1000 MHz.
cpufreq stats: 1.80 GHz:36,16%, 1.60 GHz:2,73%, 1.40 GHz:3,99%, 1.20 GHz:11,66%, 1000 MHz:45,45%  (14681)
boost state support:
Supported: yes
Active: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The availability of Turbo Core depends on your GPU driver (`radeon`, `fglrx`). But even if Turbo Core works, you will not see any indication for this unless you do a `modprobe msr`.

For details, please refer to:

- [How to set up Linux for full AMD APU power management support: Turbo Core, Cool'n'Quiet, Dynamic Power Management?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148917/79761) for a detailed technical discussion
- [How to set up a Debian system (focus on 2D or console/server) with an AMD Turbo Core APU for maximum energy and computing efficiency?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/241825/79761) for the situation with Debian, which is the basis for Ubuntu.